# Can we add new co-owners to an existing flow using another flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, administration, power-automate, flow

I want to add new co-owners to an existing flow using another power automate.

Is it possible?

Please guide me on this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Power Automate Management** connector for your requirements.

You have to use the **[Modify Flow Owners](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/flowmanagement/#modify-flow-owners)** action for adding co-owner to the existing flow.

**Example**:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Power Automate Management connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/flowmanagement)